# Rails - use info from a dropdown to supply arguments for method actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, drop-down-menu, arguments

At the moment, I have a list of projects in the projects/index view. When you click 'show' next to a project, it goes to the show view for that project. In there, you can click 'Select Project', and this passes the id for that project into the session, so that only relevant tasks related to that project are shown in other pages.

What I'm wanting to do is have a dropdown menu for the projects (so that you don't just see a massive long table of all the projects), and have two buttons next to the dropdown menu - one to see more info (i.e. go to the show view for that project), and one to 'Select Project'. How can I make it so that they have the correct info (i.e. the project id), so that they function properly? Thanks!

Here's all the relevant code:

Project dropdown:

```
<%= collection_select(:project, :id, Project.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Link to show view:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', project, :class =>"btn btn-primary btn-mini" %>
```

Link to 'Select Project'

```
<%= link_to 'Select Project', select_project_project_path(@project), :method => :post, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-small' %>
```

Select Project action in the projects controller:

```
def select_project
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  session[:project_id] = project.id
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Current project set to: #{project.name}, ID: #{project.id}"
end
```

UPDATE:

Here are the relevant routes:

```
resources :projects do
  member do
    post :select_project
  end
end
```

And the results of rake routes|grep projects:

```
 select_project_project POST   /projects/:id/select_project(.:format)  projects#select_proj
               projects GET    /projects(.:format)                     projects#index
                        POST   /projects(.:format)                     projects#create
            new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                 projects#new
           edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)            projects#edit
                project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                 projects#show
                        PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                 projects#update
                        DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                 projects#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
<%= collection_select :project, :id, Project.all, :id, :name %>
<%= link_to "Show", @project, id: "show_project_btn" %>
<%= link_to "Select" select_project_project_path(@project), id: "select_project_btn" %>

<script type="javascript">
  $('#project_id').change(function(){
    var project_id = $(this).val();
    $('#show_project_button').attr('href', '/project/' + project_id);
    $('#select_project_button').attr('href', '/projects/' + project_id + '/select_project');
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Is that written in haml or something? Mine is a .erb file - how would I translate that to work? Your code does look like what I'm after, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Tried that and I'm getting an error now saying: No route matches {:action=>"select_project", :controller=>"projects", :id=>nil} - does that mean that it's not getting the id passed to it, or could it be that on the inital page load, no id is getting passed?

Comment: It means, that I don't know what routes you have )

Comment: please show your routes related to projects `rake routes|grep projects`

Comment: I've added the relevant bits from the routes file and run rake routes - they're in my original question now. I've tried a few things based on the routes and still can't get it to work. I apologise, I'm fairly new to rails!

Comment: I'm getting the same error :S - any idea why? The only thing I can think of is that it is trying to display buttons when there is no project specified.  I've tried adding the following line after the var project id line, but it hasn't helped: if project_id == null {
     project_id == 1
    };

Answer (score 0):

You can create and use "show" and "select project" routes that are not based on the project id (and don't collide with Rails resource routes), and continue to send the project id into the controller's actions as part of the params object.

In routes.rb,

```
get 'show_project', to: 'projects#show'
get 'select_project', to: 'projects#select_project'
```

In your view, use path names like `show_project_path` and `select_project_path` for submitting your requests.